# Sping Boot AnnotationException - mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to understand how entity relationships works in Spring Boot. To understand them, I'm trying to implement the following database schema

[image]

So far I have implemented the entities that way

### User

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String email;

  private String passwordDigest;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "followerId")
  Set<User> followers;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "followedId")
  Set<User> follows;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  Set<Tweet> tweets;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date createdAt;
  
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date updatedAt;

  // constructors, getters and setters

}
```

### Relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = @Index(columnList = "follower_id, followed_id"))
class Relationship {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User followerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User followedId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    Date createdAt;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    Date updatedAt;

    // constructors, getters and setters

}
```

### Tweets

```
@Entity
public class Tweet {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    User user;

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Now, while running the application I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.entity.User.followerId in com.example.demo.entity.User.followers
```

Which looks odd to me since I made sure that

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "followerId")
Set<User> followers;
```

in User entity mattches the property of followerId in Relationship entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
User followerId;
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "followerId")
Set<User> followers;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "followedId")
Set<User> follows;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "followerId")
Set<Relationship> followers;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "followedId")
Set<Relationship> follows;
```

In User entity since the one to many relationship targets the Relationship entity